# Tableau Incorporating quarters into a line chart on x axis

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have the following tableau chart

[image]

I would like to get rid of the months and put quarters instead at the places Sep, dec, march and June

I can't see to understand how to get this done

Any help would be appreciated in this regard

Comment: select month-Date down arrow, click quarter (Continuous)

Comment: Frim your question it is not clear what do you want from either of these two- 1. Change axis ticks only while not changing the view OR 2. Change the view as per quarter?